# Extracting Strings from between dashes "-"

Tags: r

I have some strings that look like this:

```
x <- 'aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file'
```

is there a particular package or method where i can specify 1,2 or 3 to specify the string between the first second or third pair of dashes.

So the end result i should be able to extract "ttttt", "eeeee" or "2015 if specified by me.

Comment: another one `read.table(text = x, sep = '-')[, 5]`

Answer (score 2):

Not fully sure if this is what you need, but you can use `str_split` from the package `stringr` to break a string into pieces using a specified pattern. For example, in your case, `str_split(your_string, "-",)`. You could then filter the output to specify what you want to keep.

```
library(stringr)

string <- "aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file"

x<- str_split(string, "-")

x[[1]][1] #extract the first word
x[[1]][2] #extract second word
```

See documentation here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_split

Answer (score 2):

We can write a function :

```
x <- 'aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file'
return_string <- function(x, split = '-', n)  strsplit(x, split)[[1]][n + 1]

return_string(x, '-', 1)
#[1] "ttttt"
return_string(x, '-', 2)
#[1] "eeee"
return_string(x, '-', 4)
#[1] "2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit`

```
a = "aaaaa-ttttt-eeee-q4-2015-file"
b = strsplit(a, "-")[[1]][c(2,3,5)]
print(b)
```